# Beamer capital sigma sign is different

Tags: beamer, fonts

I am using beamer in overleaf and \Sigma symbols appears to be like Σ, and it is not exactly similar to the summation sign (with the extra edges). What should I do?

[image: example image]

Comment: Just use `$\sum$`  if you want the extra edges.

Comment: but I want to use hats and subscripts

Comment: "Extra edges" sounds like you're looking for a serif font.  Beamer chooses a san serif font most of the time, so you may not end up with edges after all.  It still means summation.

Comment: Then what should I do? @Teepeemm

Comment: Try loading the `sansmathfonts` package, I like that better with `beamer`

Comment: I'm a bit confused with what you're trying to do.  Why can't you use `\sum` in the code that made your image?  Could you post a minimal working example (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/107497) that uses `\sum` but doesn't quite do what you want?